# what is a floating joint physically?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What is the physics of floating joint type?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14728/what-is-a-floating-joint-physically?/) by [Abdullah](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2617/abdullah/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Floating joints only exist on URDF, not on [SDF](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=joint#joint_type) (which is the primary description format used by Gazebo).

According to URDF [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint), a floating joint "allows motion for all 6 degrees of freedom". For SDF, that would be no joint at all.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdullah](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2617/abdullah/) on 2016-11-01**:
Thank you so much for the information sir, kindly let me know, if there is a way to use a ball joint?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-11-01**:
Not a "sir" ;) You could take a look at the following tutorial, a ball joint is used for the caster wheel: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=guided_b3 <- link

**Comment by [Abdullah](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2617/abdullah/) on 2016-11-01**:
Hi,
When I click on this link that you have kindly provided, it is not working.
Please kindly let me know, if there is any other resource available.

**Comment by [Abdullah](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2617/abdullah/) on 2016-11-01**:
There is one more question, can we get ball joints by URDF? or xacro? what is the correct syntax for that?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-11-01**:
Try the link now ;) That's a lot of questions in one, I suggest you start a new question for that.